# Android 9 reboots after update to targetSDK 31

Tags: android, crash, android-sdk-tools, android-9.0-pie, android-12

Since i updated my app to complie/tragetSDK 31 it is totaly crashing exclusively android 9 devices, the devices and the emulator is restarting if i try to start the app, the only log i got from the play store pre launch report was

> Fatal AndroidRuntime Exception detected. (on a Pixel 3 with Android 9)

i also implemented the new splashscreen according to the official guide
i could find nothing on this here on SO, have you experienced this?
i updated the build tools (32-rc1) and Android Studio to the latest verrsion.

UPDATE The new Slpashscreen is causing the issue! The Splashscreen Theme in styles in the MainActivity is causing the crash, if its changed to the actual AppTheme the app starts on Android 9!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE The new Slpashscreen is causing the issue! The Splashscreen Theme in styles in the MainActivity is causing the crash, if its changed to the actual AppTheme the app starts on Android 9!
This seems like a major oversight, isnt the point of androidx to make the new splashscreen backwards compatible? it does work on Android 10,11,12 with no issue...